# Why is e acceptable in input type number

Tags: html

I have an input with a type of number. When I was testing it out, I discovered that when I typed the letter `e`, it appeared in the text box. Any other letter did not: the input was a number. Why is a letter allowed in this input type?

Comment: Maybe because [e is a mathematical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)? :)

Comment: scientific notation?

Comment: @daniel my guess is it's because it's a valid character in floating point literals

Comment: I hate math, but I guess that makes sense.